# Differential delta y does not follow answer provided in book.

Tags: calculus

I am working myself through Stewart's *Essential Calculus Early Transcendentals*. This issue concerns question 19 on page 139.

Using $f'(x) * \Delta x = dy$ to find a change in $y$, then $f(x) + \Delta y $ for the change in $y$ related to a change in $x$. It has been correct in the previous problems and I believe I understand the concept behind it.

$y = tan(x)$ 
The differential must be $dy = sec^2(x )dx$.

Then evaluate for $dy$ and $\Delta y$ if $x = \frac \pi4$ and $\Delta x = -0.1$.

Using the above equation for $dy$, 
$$ dy = sec^2(\frac \pi4) * -0.1 = -0.2 $$

then 
$$\Delta y = tan(\frac \pi4) -0.2 = 0.8$$

However, my book provides an answer of $\Delta y = -0.18237$. Were did I go wrong?

I have looked for this question online and have not found any resolution. I make my first post in this exchange seeking sage advice. Be gentle, my giants!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the correct meaning of $\Delta y$:

$
\Delta y := f(x + \Delta x) - f(x) = \tan(\pi/4 - .1) - \tan(\pi/4) \approx .817629 -1 = -.182371
$